# dimension of an image and then check the critera and also show image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I need a functionality in which i am uploading an image and checking the max criteria.if the image is bigger then max criteria then show alert msg

my code is working in jfiddle but in html page its not working.my coading is given below pls view

my coading is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script type="text/jquery">



    function readImage(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image = new Image();
    var maxh = 800;
    var maxw = 800;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function (_file) {
        image.src = _file.target.result; // url.createObjectURL(file);
        image.onload = function () {
            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type, // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                n = file.name,
                s = ~~ (file.size / 1024) + 'KB';
            if (w > maxw && h > maxh) {
                alert("Height is bigger then over max criteria pls select image max height and width                                            =2024X2024");
                alert(width);
                alert(height);
            } else {


                $('#uploadPreview').html('<img src="' + this.src + '"> ' + w + 'x' + h + ' ' + s + ' ' + t + ' ' + n + '<br>');
            }

        };
        image.onerror = function () {
            alert('Invalid file type: ' + file.type);
        };
    };

}
$("#choose").change(function (e) {
    if (this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
    var F = this.files;
    if (F && F[0]) for (var i = 0; i < F.length; i++) readImage(F[i]);
});

</script>



<style>

  #uploadPreview img {
    height:32px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body >
<input type="file" id="choose" multiple="multiple" />
<br>
<div id="uploadPreview"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Question/problem:not working in html page.
http://jsfiddle.net/5SVuA/1/

hope you understand my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have the wrong script type `script type="text/jquery"`, instead of `script type="text/javascript"`.

And move your javascript code to domready function:

```
$(function () {
    //your code here
});
```